# Find out screen id

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, gnu-screen, php

I want to start a program with SSH using PHP, which works fine, but now I want to kill the screen with PHP, but the only thing I know is the name of the screen. How do I find out the screen ID (automatically)?

Comment: `screen` or `DISPLAY`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the environment variable `$STY` to determine whether you're in a screen session and also what the name of the session is that you're inside.

#### Example

Initially we're sitting in a terminal window, not inside of a screen session.

```
$ echo $STY

$
```

Spin up a screen session:

```
$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
    31543.tscrn (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-saml.
```

Connect to it:

```
$ screen -r 31543.tscrn
```

Inside screen session:

```
$ echo $STY
31543.tscrn
$
```

#### Killing a session

With the name of the session you can kill it using `screen`.

```
$ screen -X -S tscrn kill
```

You can also use the number there too.

```
$ screen -X -S 31543 kill
```

Confirm that its been killed:

```
$ screen -ls
No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-saml.
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the `screen` program? `screen -ls` will list screen processes along with their screen name, prepended by the PID they are running from:

```
screen -S foo
screen -ls

There are screens on:
    8806.foo        (09/08/13 20:05:22)     (Attached)
```

You can use that to kill the process:

```
kill -15 $(screen -ls | grep '[0-9]*\.foo' | sed -E 's/\s+([0-9]+)\..*/\1/')
```

Alternatively, if you can identify the php process with ps, then it's parent id will be screen and you can kill that.   `pgrep -U <myusername> -f <name>` will help find the php process you want to find (note the `-f` which searches the command arguments as well as the command name). You may be running more than one php script, so `-f` will be a better mechanism to match your process. `<myusername>` would be your username, `<name>` would be a string to match the process by. Then you can use `ps -p <pid> -o ppid=` to get the screen process ID and kill that.

```
kill -15 $( ps -p $(pgrep -U fooman -f foobar_process) -o ppid= )
```